# multiple routes not working with express

Tags: express

So I am learning express, and I want to be able to make multiple routes. I've tried the following code on digital ocean and I get the message `Cannot GET /test` what am I doing wrong here?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('main page');
});

app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.send('test page');
});

app.listen(80);
```

Comment: What version of express are you using? It seems to be working fine with Express 4.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are missing a lot of the core Express features which are included in the generated template. It would be much more beneficial to you if you are simply learning to generate a template and try to understand the code from a functioning base. In order to install express globally on your system enter the following command.

```
npm install -g express
```

Once you have entered that command you are now able to generate a template via the express command. Navigate to the directory where you want the project build and enter the following command.

```
express MyAppName
```

You may also view a list of options by entering:

```
express --help
```

When the build has been generated you will need to install all the modules in your `package.json` file, to do so enter the following command.

```
npm install
```

After the successful installation of your modules you can view the generated template website my entering the following command and then navigating your browser to `localhost:3000/`.

```
node app
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should try a different port. It's working fine on express 3.5.1